# JNA Convert HICON to Java Image

Tags: java, c++, converters, jna

I knwo there is already an [question like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279134/java-windows-taskbar-using-jna-how-do-i-convert-window-icons-hicon-to-java?rq=1). But its solution was not suitable for me because with the Sehellfolder Methode you can only get 16x16 and 32x32 sized icons.
I have extracted a HICO with size of 256x256 and want to convert it into and Java Image like BufferedImage. I found and method for it to. But it does not work properly:

```
public static BufferedImage getIcon(final WinDef.HICON hIcon,int ICON_SIZE,short ICON_DEPTH,int ICON_BYTE_SIZE) {
    final int width = ICON_SIZE;
    final int height = ICON_SIZE;
    final short depth = ICON_DEPTH;
    final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    final Memory lpBitsColor = new Memory(width * height * depth / ICON_BYTE_SIZE);
    final Memory lpBitsMask = new Memory(width * height * depth / ICON_BYTE_SIZE);
    final WinGDI.BITMAPINFO info = new WinGDI.BITMAPINFO();
    final WinGDI.BITMAPINFOHEADER hdr = new WinGDI.BITMAPINFOHEADER();
    info.bmiHeader = hdr;
    hdr.biWidth = width;
    hdr.biHeight = height;
    hdr.biPlanes = 1;
    hdr.biBitCount = depth;
    hdr.biCompression = WinGDI.BI_RGB;

    final WinDef.HDC hDC = User32.INSTANCE.GetDC(null);
    final WinGDI.ICONINFO piconinfo = new WinGDI.ICONINFO();
    User32.INSTANCE.GetIconInfo(hIcon, piconinfo);

    GDI32.INSTANCE.GetDIBits(hDC, piconinfo.hbmColor, 0, height, lpBitsColor, info, WinGDI.DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    GDI32.INSTANCE.GetDIBits(hDC, piconinfo.hbmMask, 0, height, lpBitsMask, info, WinGDI.DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    int r, g, b, a, argb;
    int x = 0, y = height - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < lpBitsColor.size(); i = i + 3) {
        b = lpBitsColor.getByte(i) & 0xFF;
        g = lpBitsColor.getByte(i + 1) & 0xFF;
        r = lpBitsColor.getByte(i + 2) & 0xFF;
        a = 0xFF - lpBitsMask.getByte(i) & 0xFF;

        argb = a << 24 | r << 16 | g << 8 | b;
        image.setRGB(x, y, argb);
        x = (x + 1) % width;
        if (x == 0) {
            y--;
        }
    }

    User32.INSTANCE.ReleaseDC(null, hDC);
    GDI32.INSTANCE.DeleteObject(piconinfo.hbmColor);
    GDI32.INSTANCE.DeleteObject(piconinfo.hbmMask);

    return image;
}
```

[Resulting Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHR4V.png)

Do you know andy method that works better?

EDIT:

```
public static BufferedImage getImageByHICON(final int width, final int height, final WinNT.HANDLE hicon, final WinGDI.BITMAPINFOHEADER info) {
    final WinGDI.ICONINFO iconinfo = new WinGDI.ICONINFO();

    try {
        // GDI32 g32 = GDI32.INSTANCE;

        // get icon information

        if (!User32.INSTANCE.GetIconInfo(new WinDef.HICON(hicon.getPointer()), iconinfo)) { return null; }
        final WinDef.HWND hwdn = new WinDef.HWND();
        final WinDef.HDC dc = User32.INSTANCE.GetDC(hwdn);

        if (dc == null) {

            return null; }
        try {
            final int nBits = width * height * 4;
            // final BitmapInfo bmi = new BitmapInfo(1);

            final Memory colorBitsMem = new Memory(nBits);
            // // Extract the color bitmap
            final WinGDI.BITMAPINFO bmi = new WinGDI.BITMAPINFO();

            bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = WinGDI.BI_RGB;
            GDI32.INSTANCE.GetDIBits(dc, iconinfo.hbmColor, 0, height, colorBitsMem, bmi, WinGDI.DIB_RGB_COLORS);
            // g32.GetDIBits(dc, iconinfo.hbmColor, 0, size, colorBitsMem,
            // bmi,
            // GDI32.DIB_RGB_COLORS);
            final int[] colorBits = colorBitsMem.getIntArray(0, width * height);
            if (info.biBitCount < 32) {
                final Memory maskBitsMem = new Memory(nBits);
                // // Extract the mask bitmap
                GDI32.INSTANCE.GetDIBits(dc, iconinfo.hbmMask, 0, height, maskBitsMem, bmi, WinGDI.DIB_PAL_COLORS);
                // g32.GetDIBits(dc, iconinfo.hbmMask, 0, size,
                // maskBitsMem,
                // bmi,
                // // GDI32.DIB_RGB_COLORS);
                final int[] maskBits = maskBitsMem.getIntArray(0, width * height);
                // // // Copy the mask alphas into the color bits
                for (int i = 0; i < colorBits.length; i++) {
                    colorBits[i] = colorBits[i] | (maskBits[i] != 0 ? 0 : 0xFF000000);
                }
            }
            final BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            bi.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, colorBits, 0, height);
            return bi;
        } finally {
            com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32.INSTANCE.ReleaseDC(hwdn, dc);
        }
    } finally {
        User32.INSTANCE.DestroyIcon(new WinDef.HICON(hicon.getPointer()));
        GDI32.INSTANCE.DeleteObject(iconinfo.hbmColor);
        GDI32.INSTANCE.DeleteObject(iconinfo.hbmMask);
    }
}
```

[Better Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoRyG.png)

Comment: Could you add a link to the other question you are refering to for context?

Comment: I have added the link

Comment: Has anyone a solution?

Comment: Can you be more clear on what "does not work properly" means?

Comment: If you look at this Image https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHR4V.png . It is ugly

Comment: Check your order of operations. `0xFF - lpBitsMask.getByte(i) & 0xFF` is probably not doing what you think it is.  `0xFF - (lpBitsMask.getByte(i) & 0xFF)` might work better...

Comment: Thanks for your try. But it hasn´t changed anything ;(

Comment: Why are you subtracting the bitmask from 0xFF?   Looking at the image, it does seem something's wonky with your alpha calculation because the rest of it looks normal.  Is there sample code or docs you are following?

Comment: Yes here is the sample code: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HICON

Comment: Just guessing here comparing to reference image. Looks like you're getting "pure white" on an edge case for alpha.  Try a special case if `lpBitsMask.getByte(i)` equals zero, returning 0 for `a` instead of `0xFF`.

Comment: Is this right ?                                                                             if(lpBitsMask.getByte(i)==0) {
                a=0;
            }else{
                a = 0xFF;
            }

Comment: I have found another Method which works much better (EDIT) as you can see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoRyG.png. But not perfect. What should I change?

Comment: I fixed it finally!

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked code from [MrMarnic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10260109/mrmarnic)'s GitHub which works with any HICON (rather than file paths):

```
public static BufferedImage toImage(WinDef.HICON hicon) {
    WinDef.HBITMAP bitmapHandle = null;
    User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
    GDI32 gdi32 = GDI32.INSTANCE;

    try {
        WinGDI.ICONINFO info = new WinGDI.ICONINFO();
        if (!user32.GetIconInfo(hicon, info))
            return null;

        info.read();
        bitmapHandle = Optional.ofNullable(info.hbmColor).orElse(info.hbmMask);

        WinGDI.BITMAP bitmap = new WinGDI.BITMAP();
        if (gdi32.GetObject(bitmapHandle, bitmap.size(), bitmap.getPointer()) > 0) {
            bitmap.read();

            int width = bitmap.bmWidth.intValue();
            int height = bitmap.bmHeight.intValue();

            final WinDef.HDC deviceContext = user32.GetDC(null);
            WinGDI.BITMAPINFO bitmapInfo = new WinGDI.BITMAPINFO();

            bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.size();
            if (gdi32.GetDIBits(deviceContext, bitmapHandle, 0, 0, Pointer.NULL, bitmapInfo,
                    WinGDI.DIB_RGB_COLORS) == 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("GetDIBits should not return 0");

            bitmapInfo.read();

            Memory pixels = new Memory(bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
            bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = WinGDI.BI_RGB;
            bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;

            if (gdi32.GetDIBits(deviceContext, bitmapHandle, 0, bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, pixels, bitmapInfo,
                    WinGDI.DIB_RGB_COLORS) == 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("GetDIBits should not return 0");

            int[] colorArray = pixels.getIntArray(0, width * height);
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            image.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, colorArray, 0, width);

            return image;
        }
    } finally {
        gdi32.DeleteObject(hicon);
        Optional.ofNullable(bitmapHandle).ifPresent(gdi32::DeleteObject);
    }

    return null;
}
```