# Does setIconImages change the image size?

Tags: java, windows, winapi, java-native-interface, awt

For a proof-of-concept, I am using [`Window#setIconImages(List<? extends Image>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages-java.util.List-) with a singleton list to add a 16x16 icon to a [`JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html). In a separate program, I am utilizing native functions to extract the window's icon (see [Convert HICON to Java Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77495389/5645656)) and save it to a file. The resultant image is 32x32 pixels rather than 16x16, and the image has lost some quality:

| Window Icon | Output Image |
| --- | --- |
| [image: window icon] (16x16) | [image: output image] (32x32) |

I want to identify where the image is being upscaled to see if I can prevent the loss of quality. Namely, I want to identify if `setIconImages` or its underlying native calls are changing the image, or if the functions providing the icon from the native window are responsible for this upscale.

I am retrieving the icon handle with the following code:

```
private static HICON getIconHandle(HWND window) {
    final DWORDByReference hIconNumber = new DWORDByReference();
    LRESULT result = User32.INSTANCE.SendMessageTimeout(window, WinUser.WM_GETICON, new WPARAM(WinUser.ICON_BIG),
            new LPARAM(0), WinUser.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 500, hIconNumber);
    if (result.intValue() == 0)
        result = User32.INSTANCE.SendMessageTimeout(window, WinUser.WM_GETICON, new WPARAM(WinUser.ICON_SMALL),
                new LPARAM(0), WinUser.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 500, hIconNumber);
    if (result.intValue() == 0)
        result = User32.INSTANCE.SendMessageTimeout(window, WinUser.WM_GETICON, new WPARAM(WinUser.ICON_SMALL2),
                new LPARAM(0), WinUser.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 500, hIconNumber);
    if (result.intValue() == 0) {
        result = new LRESULT(User32.INSTANCE.GetClassLongPtr(window, WinUser.GCLP_HICON).intValue());
        hIconNumber.getValue().setValue(result.intValue());
    }
    if (result.intValue() == 0) {
        result = new LRESULT(User32.INSTANCE.GetClassLongPtr(window, WinUser.GCLP_HICONSM).intValue());
        hIconNumber.getValue().setValue(result.intValue());
    }
    if (result.intValue() == 0)
        return null;

    return new HICON(new Pointer(hIconNumber.getValue().longValue()));
}
```

And I am converting the icon to an image with this code:

```
public static BufferedImage toImage(WinDef.HICON hicon) {
    WinDef.HBITMAP bitmapHandle = null;
    User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
    GDI32 gdi32 = GDI32.INSTANCE;

    try {
        WinGDI.ICONINFO info = new WinGDI.ICONINFO();
        if (!user32.GetIconInfo(hicon, info))
            return null;

        info.read();
        bitmapHandle = Optional.ofNullable(info.hbmColor).orElse(info.hbmMask);

        WinGDI.BITMAP bitmap = new WinGDI.BITMAP();
        if (gdi32.GetObject(bitmapHandle, bitmap.size(), bitmap.getPointer()) > 0) {
            bitmap.read();

            int width = bitmap.bmWidth.intValue();
            int height = bitmap.bmHeight.intValue();

            final WinDef.HDC deviceContext = user32.GetDC(null);
            WinGDI.BITMAPINFO bitmapInfo = new WinGDI.BITMAPINFO();

            bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.size();
            if (gdi32.GetDIBits(deviceContext, bitmapHandle, 0, 0, Pointer.NULL, bitmapInfo,
                    WinGDI.DIB_RGB_COLORS) == 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("GetDIBits should not return 0");

            bitmapInfo.read();

            Memory pixels = new Memory(bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
            bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = WinGDI.BI_RGB;
            bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;

            if (gdi32.GetDIBits(deviceContext, bitmapHandle, 0, bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, pixels, bitmapInfo,
                    WinGDI.DIB_RGB_COLORS) == 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("GetDIBits should not return 0");

            int[] colorArray = pixels.getIntArray(0, width * height);
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            image.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, colorArray, 0, width);

            return image;
        }
    } finally {
        gdi32.DeleteObject(hicon);
        Optional.ofNullable(bitmapHandle).ifPresent(gdi32::DeleteObject);
    }

    return null;
}
```

After that, it's a just a good ol' fashioned [`ImageIO.write(RenderedImage, String, File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write-java.awt.image.RenderedImage-java.lang.String-java.io.File-) call.

Where is the point of failure?

Comment: At a guess, this is using an [image list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/image-list-reference) under the hood, so calling [`SetIconSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-imagelist_seticonsize) does change the size of all images in that list.

Comment: Short answer:  Yes.  Images can be resized by a native desktop system for use as window icons, taskbar icons, task list icons, and cursor images.  That’s why applications traditionally pass multiple images of varying resolutions, including 16×16, 24×24, 32×32, 48×48, 64×64, 128×128, 256×256, and 512×512.

Comment: @IInspectable is AWT calling `SetIconSize` under the hood?

Comment: @VGR I was aware that OS would pick the icon with the most appropriate resolution, but I never knew it could actually resize that icon.